# Github Actions: cannot find input file: Makefile.in

Tags: github, compiler-errors, github-actions

I'm trying to use Github Actions to compile a project, but I always get the error `cannot find input file: Makefile.in`. I don't get the error when compiling locally on my computer.

Here is my code:

```
name: C/C++ CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - run: chmod +rwx ./configure
    - name: Configure
      run: ./configure CC="gcc"
    - name: make
      run: make
```

It seems that Github is not able to create new files during a workflow run. I've also noticed that if I try to create a folder (eg. `mkdir build`), the folder isn't created (running `cd build` on the folder fails). Does anyone know how to work around this issue?

Comment: Where do you get this error, which step exactly?

Comment: During `./configure CC="gcc"`, although the issue with the workflow run in general not being able to make files or folders can occur at any point.

Comment: Does `Makefile.in` file exist in your repo? What is its path? Please include your relevant directory structure and the workflow run raw logs in your question. This seems like an invalid path issue.

Comment: No, it is generated on the fly by the configure script. Github Actions just doesn't seem to allow creating files or folders on the fly?

Comment: Yes, you can generate files on runtime on GHA runner. Did you try to verify the file with `ls` command?

Comment: Yes, I did. It doesn't show up. Same goes for folders.

Comment: Then, what do you get in logs during configure and make steps?

Comment: I made the repository public: https://github.com/Andereoo/TkinterWeb-Tkhtml. Maybe you would be willing to take a look? Thank you!

Comment: How are you building it locally? Looks like you're using Autotools, right? `configure` script is there but there's no `Makefile.in`. That's why you're last workflow is failing.

Comment: The `configure` file is supposed to create `Makefile.in`. The file doesn't seem to be made, same as how `mkdir foldername` also doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: What Linux distro and version are you using locally? And, is the same sequence of command working fine on your local dev setup?

Comment: I'm trying to use MacOS and Raspberry Pi. The same sequence of commands works fine on Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: There must be something missing here. You might other unchecked files in your repo or some deps already installed in the path. Previously, I tried to build on my Ubuntu machine and it failed with the same error (I had to install `tcl-dev` and `tk-dev` packages initially).